# How to handle failure of Realm instance creation?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am trying to setup a global realm object as shown below:

```
do {
      self.realm = try Realm(configuration: baseConfig) 
    } catch {
        fatalError("Error occurred while trying to initialise realm \(error)")
    }
```

However, the fatalError is being called every so often. According to the Realm documentation this is not unexpected and I should be able to handle the error in the catch.

> Like any disk I/O operation, creating a Realm instance could sometimes fail if resources are constrained. In practice, this can only happen the first time a Realm instance is created on a given thread.

I'm thinking of impelementing something like this where I just retry a second time.

```
do {
  self.realm = try Realm(configuration: baseConfig) 
} catch {
   do {
      self.realm = try Realm(configuration: baseConfig) 
    } catch {
        fatalError("Error occurred while trying to initialise realm \(error)")
    } 
}
```

My question is if it is guaranteed that creating a Realm instance can only fail once on a thread, why doesn't Realm just retry itself?

Is there a standard way of initializing the Realm object if it fails the first time?

Comment: If there are the same conditions you will get the same results no matter how many times you try to create your db i think

Answer (score 0):

```
 func createDB ()

 {
      do {
           self.realm = try Realm(configuration: baseConfig) 
      } catch {

         if(counter < 3)
         {  
              self.createDB()

              counter = counter + 1 
         }
         else
         {
            fatalError("Error occurred while trying to initialise realm \(error)")
          }

      } 


  }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the counter increment be placed before the recursive call?